# I was trying to scrape a website using BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I've got it working its printing fine in the notebook, but I didn't understand why its showing unnecessary text in the excel file. here is the code snippet.

```
import csv


file = open('targeted_prods.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(file)

writer.writerow(['Product Name', 'Brand', 'Price'])
for prod_info in prod_prev:
    prod_name = prod_info.find('div', {'class': 'product-name'}).h3.a.attrs['title'].text
    brand_name = prod_info.find('div', {'class': 'product-name'}).find('h4').text
    price = prod_info.find('div', {'class': 'product-price'}).find('span').text
    print(prod_name + ' ' + brand_name + ' ' + price)
writer.writerow([prod_name.encode('utf-8'), brand_name.encode('utf-8'), price.encode('utf-8')])
```

Excel file:

[image]

Comment: That's the result of doing `.encode('utf-8')` on things - is there any reason why you're doing that?

Comment: The reason for that is I'm trying to write the scraped information in excel file. I apologize if it is not correct way. I'm just a beginner.